# Tkinter replace line in note pad

Tags: python, tkinter, replace

So I have an app that will export a number of fields into a notepad in a format. Works ok. However, I've tried doing the same thing but replacing an existing line in a notepad and I'm having problems. Rather than import it's giving me a `'results' not defined`. I'm very new at this and any help would be great.

Below is the full code. If you comment line 16-29 and uncomment 32-44 it will work in a blank notepad. I'm trying to get the replace to work.

The `user.txt` file has a line that I want to replace everything inside the quotes:

```
Subject = "C=US, O=Testing Co, CN= Script Test, OU = OU Example, O = Example, L = Houston, S = Texas, C = US"
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def save_info():
    country_info = country.get()
    organization_info = organization.get()
    common_name = common.get()
    org_unit = org.get()
    location_info = location.get()
    state_info = state.get()

    results = (country_info,organization_info,common_name,org_unit,location_info,
               state_info)
    final = results
    print(final)

file = open("user.txt", "r")
replacement = ""
# using the for loop
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    changes = line.replace("C=US, O=Testing Co, CN= Script Test, OU = OU Example, "
                           "O = Example, L = Houston, S = Texas, C = US", results)
    replacement = replacement + changes

file.close()
# opening the file in write mode

fout = open("user.txt", "w")
fout.write(replacement)
fout.close()

#file = open("user.txt","w")
# file.write('"'"C:" + country_info  + ",")
# file.write(" ")
# file.write("O:" + organization_info + ",")
# file.write(" ")
# file.write("CN:" + common_name +",")
# file.write(" ")
# file.write("OU:" + org_unit +",")
# file.write(" ")
# file.write("L:" + location_info +",")
# file.write(" ")
# file.write("S:" + state_info +'"')
# file.close()

app = Tk()

app.geometry("500x500")

app.title("Certificate Request Creation")

heading = Label(text="Certificate Request Creation",fg="black",bg="green",width="500",
                height="3",font="10")

heading.pack()

country = StringVar()
organization = StringVar()
common = StringVar()
org = StringVar()
location = StringVar()
state = StringVar()

country_text = Label(text="Country Code:")
organization_text = Label(text="Organization")
common_text = Label(text="Common Name")
org_unit_text = Label(text="Organizational Unit")
location_info_text = Label(text="Location/City")
state_info_text = Label(text="State")

country_text.place(x=15,y=65)
organization_text.place(x=15,y=115)
common_text.place(x=15,y=165)
org_unit_text.place(x=15,y=215)
location_info_text.place(x=15,y=265)
state_info_text.place(x=15,y=310)

country_name_entry = Entry(textvariable=country,width="30")
organization_entry = Entry(textvariable=organization,width="30")
common_entry = Entry(textvariable=common,width="30")
org_unit_entry = Entry(textvariable=org,width="30")
location_info_entry = Entry(textvariable=org,width="30")
state_info_entry = Entry(textvariable=state,width="30")

country_name_entry.place(x=15,y=85)
organization_entry.place(x=15,y=135)
common_entry.place(x=15,y=185)
org_unit_entry.place(x=15,y=235)
location_info_entry.place(x=15,y=285)
state_info_entry.place(x=15,y=335)

button = Button(app,text="Create",command=save_info,width="30",height="2",
                bg="grey")

button.place(x=150,y=400)

mainloop()
```

Comment: note that "results" is local in scope to the function def save_info().  If you want to access the results variable outside that function you'll have to make it global.

Comment: Also, looks like the line `changes = line.replace("C=US, O=Testing Co, CN= Script Test, OU = OU Example, " "O = Example, L = Houston, S = Texas, C = US", results)` is run before `save_info()` is called.

Comment: I decided to drop results and just use the state_info, etc. However, you are correct. changes is running before save_info(). How would I reorder that?